# Which is the proper verb in repression of anger

Tags: word-choice

> At work he always repress/control/restrain his anger.

Which verb is more natural here?

Comment: I assume you meant "refrain" and not "retrain"

Comment: The dictionary definitions of those three words should help you determine which one to use.  Additionally, I think you probably mean *at work,* instead of *among work*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though "control" is the most common of the three words, "repress" and "restrain" will also sound natural when discussing anger or other emotions. Which word you choose depends on what exactly you want to say.

Let's imagine we're talking about a man named Bob. Bob has a short temper, but he fears if he acts angrily while at work, he might lose his job.

**"Control"**

> At work he always controls his anger.

This suggests that Bob is disciplined. He may feel angry, but he is able to control how much of that anger he expresses.

**"Restrain"**

> At work he always restrains his anger.

This suggests that Bob is struggling with his anger. He can keep himself from shouting, swearing, or hitting things, but he cannot stop himself from expressing his anger in smaller ways.

**"Repress"**

> At work he always represses his anger.

This suggests that Bob is hiding his anger. He may be doing so without even thinking about it. His anger is so overwhelming the he has to pretend it's not there while he's working, but it may suddenly come out later.